# SQL : Speed considerations : multiplication by 0 / 1 vs conditional action

Tags: sql, sql-server

Would there be any significant speed difference between the following queries ?

```
- SELECT value * coeff from Table

- SELECT CASE WHEN coeff = 0 THEN 0 ELSE value END FROM Table
```

I know I could just try & see, but I am sure you will have interesting comments to make about how various DB engines would handle that, and things that the few tests I would make would miss.

Comment: Carefull what you measure here. Slower may just a a notch more CPU load given that you have a network protocol to the application on top.

Comment: @hvd : sorry I had made a mistake in the query. Fixed. (you understood the idea)

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight - The coefficient is `0 or 1` according to the question title

Comment: Dang it, didn't even notice that in the title :o

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be any significant speed differences.

At the lowest level you need to load both values into registers in the CPU.  Then the difference is roughly...

```
Load coeff into register1
Load value into register2
If register1 is not 0, skip the next operation
Load 0 into register2
Return value in register2
```

vs

```
Load coeff into register1
Load value into register2
register2 = register1 * register2
Return value in register2
```

The second is always 4 operations.  The first is 5 operations when coef is non-zero.

But the first version has very simple operations.  The multiplication in the second will be more intensive.  As far as I know, integer multiplication of 0 or 1 is still about as fast as you get.  If VALUE is a Float, however, it will be more intensive.

*(This is all from a basic working knowledge, not any expertise.)*

That all said, however, the difference will be much much less than loading data from disk, or transmition over tcp/ip.

You should run a profiler and measure the CPU cycles used by each.  Not the time taken.  You may find you use very slightly less CPU with one version over the other.  And yet see almost no difference in total time taken.

Comment: A wholly different possibility is that the SQL engine translates it as something like `SELECT 0 FROM table WHERE coeff = 0 UNION ALL SELECT value FROM table WHERE coeff <> 0` before any rows are read, for example because of an index on coeff. In that case, your answer doesn't really work.

Comment: @hvd - It won't ever do that.  It is possible for *you* to refactor the code in that way, but I have never experienced the optimiser doing that itself.  It's just too narrow an optimisation, and is one left to the programmer.

Comment: "I have never experienced the optimiser doing that itself" does not imply "It won't ever do that". When the tables are large enough for this to make a difference (otherwise, you really shouldn't care, as you also noted), it might make sense to set up the table as a partitioned view, with `coeff` as a partitioning column, and SQL Server would surprise me if it didn't optimise away a `WHEN coeff = 0` in a partitioning table with a check constraint `coeff = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a difference in resulting data-types between multiply and case columns.

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp (value DECIMAL(19, 2), coeff BIT)

INSERT  #Tmp SELECT 15, 1
INSERT  #Tmp SELECT 16, 0

SELECT  value * coeff AS final_value_mult
        , CASE WHEN coeff = 0 THEN 0 ELSE value END AS final_value_case
INTO    aaa
FROM    #Tmp

--DROP TABLE aaa, #Tmp
```

Then script table `aaa` in SSMS

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aaa](
    [final_value_mult] [decimal](38, 4) NULL,
    [final_value_case] [decimal](19, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Obviously the multiplication escalated precision/scale of the `value` data-type. `CASE` is much more immune to such unexpected results.